# With git, How do I move the master branch back to the state before I made commits?

Tags: git

I forked a repository on github, then cloned it to my machine.  I made multiple commits, but then decided I should have made the changes to a new branch and not to master.  So I created a new branch from the most recent commit, and continued making lots more changes on the new branch. I pushed the new branch back to my fork of the repo and all seems fine.

Of the changes I made to master on my local machine, I never pushed any back to the repo.  At least, I didn't push them as "master".  So when I check out master, it says it's 18 commits ahead of origin/master.

I would like to "backup" my local master to match the state of the master in the repo.  I want to retain all the commits I made, but only through the the other (cwworking) branch.

Nobody else is using my git hub repo, so there are no issues of confusing any other developer.

Isn't this just a matter of somehow telling git to make the master branch "point" to the correct older commit?  I want the master on my local machine to point to 0b58da67 like it does in my repo.  How do I do that? Is it not as simple as this?

Comment: Do you want the pointer to go back to the remote/master pointer or do you want to push the changes on the master that you couldn't push from the new local branch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following answer assumes that you incorrectly made a number of commits (let's say 3) to `master`, which you actually intended to go into a new branch.  You then branched off `master`, pushed, but now you have three unwanted commits on top of `master`.  You can nuke those three commits by using this:

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard HEAD~3
```

At this point, you should be able to pull the latest `master` branch from the remote with no difficulties:

```
git pull origin master
```

In general, `git reset --hard` should be used with caution.  But in this particular case, no one else saw those three commits, and you don't want them there.

Comment: That worked.  Thanks.  it's just so complex I couldn't tell which command was correct to use.  I thought reset --hard might be the way to go but wasn't sure if my commits (now in the log for the other branch) might get lost or if something else I didn't understand might get messed up.

Comment: @CurtWelch Yes...there is definitely a learning curve to Git, and you're right to ask for help if you aren't sure.  Eventually, you will just see pretty little linked lists of commits in your head.  Until that happens, you have Stack Overflow :-)

Comment: Just to be clear for other readers, since the commit I wanted to go back to was many commits back, I just used this form of the git reset:  "reset --hard 0b58da67d0866dc9475c529e88182825a6b8e210' to reset to the specific commit from the log.

Answer (score 1):

the easiest to reset so many commits (18) and to point the branch to the remote head, is to remove the branch locally, and to again fetch the remote branch.

```
git checkout otherbranch
git branch -d master
git fetch
git checkout master
```

Comment: That's neat.  I wouldn't have thought of doing it like that.  But it did occur to me I could have just deleted my entire local directory tree and cloned the repository again to get the effect I wanted.

Comment: I don't feel that I understand the full complexity of the underlying data structures git uses to store revisions so I never trust that a command like "delete branch" doesn't have unintended side effects that will mess up my repository. If I had a deep understanding of the repository data structures, I could better conclude what every command was really doing.

Comment: This is probably a cleaner option as it will preserve the local commits in case of mistake (for example, what if you mistakenly _did_ want to add ~3, but not ~2 and ~1?). @CurtWelch It may help to consider _remote_ branches to be unique and distinct from your _local_ branches. For example, you may find merging local branches instead of `origin/branchname` doesn't bring in all the remote changes if you haven't explicitly updated them first!